# How do I change the details of a flag I submitted?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a question as being off topic and assigned it to one of the four available other SE's to be assigned to.

Immediately after I submitted it I realized that an SE not listed would be better suited for the question. I flagged the message again with more description and was told that I already flagged it.

I also checked in my "Helpful flags" page off my profile but couldn't find anything in there to edit it.

Is there a way to edit my flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can only submit another flag providing your first flag was declined.

I have declined your flag so you should be able to flag again.

Comment: Thanks! Reflagged with the way I wanted it to be.